# Get everything before the nth occurrence of a string

Tags: bash

I have a file that contains a line similar to the one below:

```
call mvn liquibase:updateSQL -P profileName -Dusername=username -Dpassword=password -Dvarchar=nvarchar -Dnumber=numeric -Dchar=nchar -Ddate=datetime
```

What I want to do is extract the `profileName`, how do I go about extract everything after '-P ', and then everything before the nth occurrence of ' -D'?

I will be running this on different files and potentially the profileName could be in a different position to the one above.

The expected output I am looking to get is: `profileName`

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add expected output here, as it is not clear.

Comment: Hi Ravinder, I have added the expected output, cheers!

Comment: How about that statement where you need everything before nth occurrence before -D option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell me if this will do the work as expected :

```
grep -oP '(?<=-P )\w+(?= )' file_to_parse
```

This pattern say that you want word after "-P " and before " "

Comment: What if OP really wants everything before _n_ th `-D`?

Comment: I did want everything before the nth -D, but this grep command is another solution I never thought of, this worked like a charm, thank you.

Comment: @Bob Well, in that case you should edit the question to reflect your real requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=" "} /^-D/{c++} f&&c<1{b=b $0 OFS} /^-P/{f=1} END{print b}' file
profileName
```

Control the amount of needed `-D`s with the `c<n` in `f&&c<1{b=b $0 OFS}`.